# How can we use string functions within join relation statement

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
SELECT * 
FROM StudentDetails 
JOIN StudentMaster 
ON Right(concat('000000', StudentDetails.ID),6) = StudentMaster.ID
```

Data is as below:
StudentDetails Table

```
 ID         Fathers Name
 123        Martin
 124        Mike
```

StudentMaster Table

```
 ID       Name    Class
 000123   John    10
 000124   Mark    11
```

The o/p of query should be as:

```
 ID         Fathers Name    ID       Name    Class
 123        Martin          000123   John    10
 124        Mark            000124   Mike    11
```

Comment: In both tables StudentMaster & StudentDetails ID has varchar datatype

Comment: Whats wrong with your query??/

Comment: No result after executing this query

Comment: thank you Marko & Praveen .......it wasnt query issue .... that Column was misspelled....